# In bar chart, is it possible to create a bar only marker in the current month (projection)?

Tags: apexcharts

I want to create a marker, to make the value projection, but only to the bar of the current month.[image: enter image description here]![enter image description here]

Comment: Show us what you have tried.

Comment: I thought of adapting a graph of the combined type (bars and lines), where in the line I'll only define a value, this way would have a marker, which would be the projection.

Comment: I added an image to illustrate the forecast of the data

Comment: You should try yaxis.annotation - https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/annotations/#yaxis to draw shapes on custom values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To draw shapes on certain values, you can try annotations. Using [yaxis.annotations](https://apexcharts.com/docs/options/annotations/), you will be able to draw text as well as a shape on y-values.

A complete example of how to use annotations can be found [here](https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/line-charts/line-chart-annotations/)